# Virtual Slots Implementation

Tags: c++, optimization, game, random, windows

What I can do to make this code more efficient?

It is supposed to be like one of those slot machines where you gamble on it and stuff (like at a casino).

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>  

using namespace std;

int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    int slot1;
    int slot2;
    int slot3;
    double total_money = 0;
    double total_wins = 0;
    double total_tries = 0;
    double win_percentage;
    char play_again;

    cout << "Welcomes to Virtual Slots." << endl;  // Welcome the user
    cout << "Match 2, win that amount." << endl;  // Explain prizes
    cout << "Match 3, win 3x that amount.\n" << endl;

    do {

        slot1 = rand() % 10 + 1;     // Get random numbers for slots
        slot2 = rand() % 10 + 1;
        slot3 = rand() % 10 + 1;

        cout << "****SLOTS!!****" << endl;
        cout << "***************" << endl;
        cout << "* [" << slot1 << "] [" << slot2 << "] [" << slot3 << "] *" << endl;  // Show slots
        cout << "***************\n" << endl;

        if (slot1 == slot2 == slot3) {  // If all three slots match, user getx 3x money

            cout << "THREE TIMES MATCH!!" << endl;
            cout << "You win $" << (slot1 * 3) << ".\n" << endl;

            total_money += slot1;  // Count money
            total_wins++;  // Count wins
        }

        else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot1 == slot3 || slot2 == slot3) {  // if user gets 2 slots matched, user gets that amount of money

            cout << "TWO TIMES MATCH!!" << endl;
            cout << "You win $" << slot1 << ".\n" << endl;

            total_money += slot1;  // Count money
            total_wins++;  // Count wins
        }

        else {  // No match, no money

            cout << "NO MATCH.\n" << endl;
        }

        total_tries++;  // Count tries

        win_percentage = (total_wins / total_tries);  // Percentage of wins

        cout << "Current Total: $" << setprecision(4) << total_money << endl;                // Show user his statistics
        cout << "Win Percentage: " << setprecision(3) << win_percentage << "%" << endl;

        cout << "Play Again? (Y/N) " << endl;  // Ask the user if s/he wants to play again
        cin >> play_again;

        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");

    } while (play_again != 'N');  // Keep going until user says No

    cout << "See you next time!" << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (slot1 == slot2 == slot3)` does *not* do what you seem to expect.

Comment: @MartinR what does it do then?

Comment: @Kawaiiii It compares `slot1` and `slot2` then compares the resulting `bool` to `slot3`.

Comment: So should I do `if ((slot1 == slot2) && (slot2 == slot 3))`?

Comment: And why does the user win slot1$ if slot2 == slot3 in the second case?

Comment: @Kawaiiii Yes. That would be better.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, didn't notice I did that. I'll change it.

Comment: Should I change anything else, guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual improvements we often suggest here on Code Review:

### Using namespace:

Try not to `using namespace std`. Read a discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Instead, just explicitly declaring the elements you are using would be better:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
... etc...
```

Or don't do any of that and prefix library calls with `std::`. Not that much more typing anyway.

### `system("PAUSE")` & friends:

The `system()` function asks the OS to run whatever program you specify as its argument. It just so happens that on Windows there are two programs in the default path called "PAUSE" and "CLS". This is not portable. On Unix those programs do not exist. But the biggest evil of `system()` is that it is a major security hole. For example, if a hacker manages to replace "CLS" with an exploit program, your program is going to be the one who fires it. So no serious code outside a learning demo should use those. Be aware of this issue.

### Windows extensions:

`_getch()` and `<conio.h>` are Windows extensions. You can replace `_getch()` with the standard [`std::cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

### C++11 `<random>` library:

The new standard has introduced a more powerful pseudo-random number generation library: [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/). This library should be used instead of `rand()`, `srand()` for new code.

### Funky `if`:

This

```
if (slot1 == slot2 == slot3)
```

As was noted in the comments, is nonsense. You have to use the `&&` (AND) operator:

```
if ((slot1 == slot2) && (slot2 == slot3)) {  // If all three slots match, user getx 3x money
```